# QMK Bootloader not found

Tags: arch-linux, usb, keyboard, usb-device, flash

I'm trying to flash my DZ60RGB V2 keyboard on Arch Linux. I installed [qmk](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/qmk/) package setup qmk_toolbox using qmk setup command.

In the process it warned me about missing udev rules which I added when setting up

```
⚠ Missing or outdated udev rules for 'atmel-dfu' boards. Run 'sudo cp /home/s1n7ax/qmk_firmware/util/udev/50-qmk.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/'.
⚠ Missing or outdated udev rules for 'kiibohd' boards. Run 'sudo cp /home/s1n7ax/qmk_firmware/util/udev/50-qmk.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/'.
⚠ Missing or outdated udev rules for 'stm32' boards. Run 'sudo cp /home/s1n7ax/qmk_firmware/util/udev/50-qmk.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/'.
⚠ Missing or outdated udev rules for 'bootloadhid' boards. Run 'sudo cp /home/s1n7ax/qmk_firmware/util/udev/50-qmk.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/'.
⚠ Missing or outdated udev rules for 'usbasploader' boards. Run 'sudo cp /home/s1n7ax/qmk_firmware/util/udev/50-qmk.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/'.
⚠ Missing or outdated udev rules for 'massdrop' boards. Run 'sudo cp /home/s1n7ax/qmk_firmware/util/udev/50-qmk.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/'.
⚠ Missing or outdated udev rules for 'caterina' boards. Run 'sudo cp /home/s1n7ax/qmk_firmware/util/udev/50-qmk.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/'.
```

After that compiled default keymap successfully and flashed while in the Bootloader mode.

```
$ qmk compile -kb dztech/dz60rgb/v2 -km default


$ qmk flash -kb dztech/dz60rgb/v2 -km default
QMK Firmware 0.13.34
Making dztech/dz60rgb/v2 with keymap default and target flash

avr-gcc (GCC) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Size before:
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      0   26626       0   26626    6802 .build/dztech_dz60rgb_v2_default.hex

Copying dztech_dz60rgb_v2_default.hex to qmk_firmware folder                                        [OK]
Checking file size of dztech_dz60rgb_v2_default.hex                                                 [OK]
 * The firmware size is fine - 26626/28672 (92%, 2046 bytes free)
Bootloader not found. Trying again every 0.5s (Ctrl+C to cancel).....^Cmake[1]: *** [tmk_core/avr.mk:331: flash] Interrupt
```

I also tried to erase through dfu-programmer which failed again.

```
$ dfu-programmer atmega32u4 erase
dfu-programmer: no device present.
```

I tried using sudo but the result was the same. I tried the same thing on Ubuntu 21.04 which result in the same error. How ever via identifies the keyboard as DZ60RGB V2 and I can make key changes fine.

Edit:

lsusb identifies the keyboard as followr

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 445a:1121 DZTECH DZ60RGB
```

When it is connected in Bootloader mode, the device is is shown as follows.

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 03eb:2045 Atmel Corp. LUFA Mass Storage Demo Application
```

Comment: Most likely, a ***reliable*** method will be connecting a switch between RESET and GND and ***double-clicking*** that switch to put the board into bootloader mode for 8 seconds. This is sufficiently long to manually start AVRDUDE from the command line (with the generated .hex file as one of its inputs). Something like `/home/embo/temp2/2020-06-04/arduino-1.8.12/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/embo/temp2/2020-06-04/arduino-1.8.12/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:AEK11_mod_default.hex:i` (where installing

Comment: cont' - the [Arduino IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino_IDE) is a way to get AVRDUDE installed (if nothing else). It is also a way to easily get to the commandline parameters by spying on what the Arduino IDE is doing (enable ***"Show verbose output during"*** ... ***"upload"*** (menu *File* → *Preferences*)). This is a relatively straightforward way, without a lot of guesswork.

Comment: (The file extension *.hex* indicates it is likely a controller based on an AVR microcontroller, probably [ATmega32U4](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega32U4) (the most common for this purpose))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It could be any number of reasons, but usually it's some poorly documented bootloader method or you have accidentally removed the keymap that included the original RESET code. Try this:

- Hold down ESC while plugging it in
- Flip the switch on the PCB to BL and then plug it in
- Hold FN + \. Try while plugging it in and while it's plugged in
- Short the reset pin (I think pin 13 (RST)) with any of the ground pins (GND). Be careful not to hit any of the powered pins (+5V).

If that doesn't work, it may be a QMK issue with the default bootloader. You can try manually setting it with -bl dfu (if it is a DFU microcontroller). The bootloader may be incorrect in the default file. Check the text in either rules.mk in the keyboard folder (not keymap, I believe).

Best of luck, hope this is not too late.